# What is the vega profile of an up-and-out call option? And why is this important in structuring?

Tags: options, greeks, barrier, vega

I had this question during an interview but I can't seem to find the answer on the internet.

Comment: Of an Up and Out, I assume. It (vega) can switch from positive to negative, unlike a regular call.

Comment: The next question is then "what is easier to hedge, a continuous barrier, or a barrier only at expiry?"

Comment: @Ivan Wouldn't a long position in options will always have positive vega?